# Solr Spell Check returning false positives correctlySpelled()

Tags: json, xml, solr, solr5

I am currently using solr 5x on a local server and using a Drupal instance to generate all the indexes. After a lot of configuration, i got to a point i am fairly happy with the solr implementation.

However, one of the problems i have just noticed is that **correct spellings** are still counted as **misspelled** and are still offered suggestions.

`"correctlySpelled":false`

As you can see in the **JSON output**, both words: **license** and **vehicle** are spelt correctly and are still classed as **incorrect**.

```
"spellcheck":{
   "suggestions":[
      "license",
      {
         "numFound":3,
         "startOffset":0,
         "endOffset":7,
         "suggestion":[
            "licensed",
            "licensee",
            "licenser"
         ]
      },
      "vehicle",
      {
         "numFound":3,
         "startOffset":8,
         "endOffset":15,
         "suggestion":[
            "chicle",
            "pedicle",
            "vehiculate"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "correctlySpelled":false,
   "collations":[
      "collation",
      "licensed chicle",
      "collation",
      "licensed pedicle",
      "collation",
      "licensed vehiculate",
      "collation",
      "licenser chicle",
      "collation",
      "licenser pedicle"
   ]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on why it would produce false positives?

**URL Encoded Query**:

`http://192.168.33.10:8983/solr/drupal/spell?q=license+vehicle&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.accuracy=0.7&spellcheck.collate=true&defType=edismax&json.nl=flat&omitHeader=true&qf=ts_title^1&fl=*,score&start=0&fq=index_id:"new_index"&fq=hash:"96z3wm"&rows=10&wt=json&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true`

**Query:**

```
q = license+vehicle
spellcheck = true
spellcheck.accuracy = 0.7
spellcheck.collate = true
defType = edismax
json.nl = flat
omitHeader = true
qf = ts_title^1
fl = *,score
start = 0
fq = index_id:"new_index"
fq = hash:"96z3wm"
rows = 10
wt = json
stopwords = true
lowercaseOperators = true
```

Relevant part of schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" /> -->
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" /> -->

  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="multiterm">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" /> -->

    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Relevant part of solrconfig.xml**

```
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">spell</str> <!--The default field for spell checking. -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">file</str> <!--default or file or jarowinkler as mentioned above. -->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">spell</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
      <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="classname">solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="name">file</str>
      <str name="sourceLocation">spellings.txt</str>
      <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellcheckerFile</str>
    </lst>

  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a non-stemmed field as your source for spelling corrections? You might not actually have the terms you think you have in the index. Also, from the old wiki: If "spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest" is not specified, the default behavior is to generate suggestions and to report "correctlySpelled" as "false" if at least 1 term is not in the index (Document Frequency == 0) regardless of the number of results returned.

Comment: @MatsLindh - there is a reference of the `spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest` in the `solr.SearchHandler`. The results are returning fine as mentioned above, so the terms are being indexed. Just the spellchecker values is ignoring a correct spelling.

Comment: Is the number of hits for the token larger than the maxResultsForSuggest then?

Answer (score 0):

This is something which i have also experienced with Solr . It happens in an unpredictable fashion . The approach i use to avoid such conditions is to make a spell pre check with edismax parameter "mm" , by setting it to 100 . Try setting mm=100 in your edismax query , and see if that works . Then you make a flow , where your first strictly only spell check the word , and then pass it on to search query handler . When you specify mm=100 , don't pass your phrase in any kind of double quotes, just pass it as is it . Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: I have set the mm value to 100 but i dont get any results back, just the same suggestions. Can you please elaborate, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tell me what other parameters are you sending along with mm ?

Comment: its just mm=100, same query, which i wanted to understand whether i need to reformat my request to support edismax. Also, what other things do i need to send?